# Sequence in C[0,1] for which the weak limit is 0 but the infinity norm is 1.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I want to find a sequence $(x_n)\in C[0,1]$ for which the weak limit is 0 ($\sigma-\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0$), but $||x_n||_\infty=1$ for all $n$.

Here is our definition of the weak limit:

Let $(x_n)\subset X$ be a sequence.
We say that $(x_n)$ is weakly convergent and $x\in X$ is its weak limit, $x=\sigma-\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x'(x_n) = x'(x)$ for all $x'\in X'$.

Comment: $x' \in X$ seems to be a typo.

Comment: Thank you, I just fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint nondegenerate intervals (that is, intervals of nonzero lengths) within $[0, 1]$. For each $n$, let $x_n \in C[0, 1]$ be a nonnegative function with norm 1 supported within $A_n$ (say, a piecewise linear spike function supported on $A_n$). Then I claim $x_n$ weakly converges to 0. Indeed, since the dual space of $C[0, 1]$ is the space of complex-valued Radon measures on $[0, 1]$, which is linearly spanned by Radon probability measures, it suffices to prove $\int x_n d\mu \rightarrow 0$ for all Radon probability measure $\mu$ on $[0, 1]$. Assume otherwise. Then there exists $\mu$ and $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\int x_n d\mu > \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. But as $x_n$ are nonnegative functions of norm 1 supported on $A_n$, we have $\int x_n d\mu \leq \mu(A_n)$. Thus, $\mu(A_n) > \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. As $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint, $\mu$ cannot be a probability measure, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant $x'\in X'$, the dual of $C[0,1]$ when $C[0,1]$ is provided with the sup norm, then you can take $x_n(t)=n^{2}t(\frac  2 n -t)$ for $0 \leq t
\leq \frac 2 n$ and $0$ for $t>\frac  1  2n$. Take $x\equiv 0$. By Dominated Convergnce Theorem we get $x'(x_n) \to 0$ for every $x'\in X'$. [Recall that $x'(x_n)=\int_0^{1}x_n(t)d\mu_n(t)$ for some real measure $\mu$).  However, $\|x_n\|_{\infty}=1$ for every $n$.